# как R нанести дополнительные точки на график

Tags: графика, r

Подскажите пожалуйста как нанести дополнительные точки(метки) на график?

```
# данные
a = c(641,642,642,642,640,639,640,641,640,640,640,639,638,645,649,641,647,655,660,667,660,662,665,669,680,683,673,675,685,690)
b = c( 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
data = cbind(a,b)
       a  b
 [1,] 641  1
 [2,] 642 NA
 [3,] 642 NA
 [4,] 642 NA
 [5,] 640 NA
 [6,] 639 -1
 [7,] 640 NA
 [8,] 641 NA
 [9,] 640 NA
[10,] 640 NA

# строим график по данным (a)
plot(a,t="l")
```

Как нанести точки(метки) на график из столбца (b)?
Прикладываю график для примера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения задачи достаточно разобраться с каким выходными данные работают функции `plot` и `points`. Им нужно передать координаты и дополнительные атрибуты.

Вектор `b` содержит в себе информацию о необходимости нанесения точки, а также о цвете. Сам координаты для точек береём из изначального вектора, а цвета из знака.

В решении ниже я переименовал входные данные для лучшего понимания смысла их использования при построении графика.

```
# кординаты Y
y <- c(641,642,642,642,640,639,640,641,640,640,640,639,638,645,649,641,647,655,660,667,660,662,665,669,680,683,673,675,685,690)
# кординаты X
x <- seq_along(y)
# разметка для нанесения точек
p <- c( 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
# индекс непустых элементов
p_idx <- !is.na(p)
# построение граифка
plot(x = x, y = y, type = "l")
# нанесение точек
points(x = x[p_idx], y = y[p_idx], col = ifelse(p[p_idx] > 0, "green", "red"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение на `ggplot2`:

```r
y <- c(641,642,642,642,640,639,640,641,640,640,640,639,638,645,649,641,647,655,660,667,660,662,665,669,680,683,673,675,685,690)
x <- seq_along(y)
p <- c( 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
DF <- data.frame(x, y)
DF$color <- ifelse(p > 0, "green", "red")
ggplot(DF, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point(data = DF[!is.na(DF$color), ], aes(color = color)) +
  scale_colour_identity() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]